# Is it possible to copy the firmware from one SUN server to another SUN server?

Tags: sun, firmware

There is no valid account for the oracle support site.
I could not download the latest release. V440,Sun Fire V440 and Netra 440 Flash PROM Update POST 4.30.4.a OBP 4.30.4.a OpenBoot 4.30,
https://support.oracle.com/epmos/faces/ui/patch/PatchDetail.jspx?patchId=142707-01,
https://getupdates.oracle.com/all_unsigned/142707-01.zip

There are 3 SUN Fire V440 servers. The firmware version 4.18, 4.22. and 4.30.

```
bash-2.03# /usr/platform/SUNW,Sun-Fire-V240/sbin/prtdiag -v
```

**Server 1 SUN FIRE V440**

```
   System PROM revisions:
    ----------------------
    OBP 4.18.10 2006/03/03 13:57 Sun Fire V440,Netra 440
    OBDIAG 4.18.10 2006/03/03 14:10
```

**Server 2 SUN FIRE V440**

```
System PROM revisions:
----------------------
OBP 4.30.4.a 2010/01/06 14:45 Sun Fire V440,Netra 440
OBDIAG 4.30.4 2010/01/06 15:01
```

**Is it possible to copy the firmware from server 2 OBP 4.30.4 to other servers?**

Update 1. I found the active mirrors of the site sunsolve.sun.com (7.01.2018) with patches OS Solaris 8, 9, 10 and firmware.

1. ftp://ftp.nstu.ru/pub/mirrors/sunsolve.sun.com/patches/
2. ftp://ftp.lanet.lv/pub/unix/sun-info/sun-patches/
3. http://ftp.gnome.org/mirror/archive/ftp.sunet.se/pub/security/vendor/sun/patches/all_unsigned/
4. http://ftp.icm.edu.pl/packages/sun-patches/

Update 2. Patch for sun fire v440, netra 440 (Release: OBP 4.22.11, POST 4.22.11, OBDIAG 4.22.11)

ftp://ftp.nstu.ru/pub/mirrors/sunsolve.sun.com/patches/121685-01.README
ftp://ftp.nstu.ru/pub/mirrors/sunsolve.sun.com/patches/121685-01.zip

```
Install Requirements: None                      

Solaris Release: 8 9 10

SunOS Release: 5.8 5.9 5.10

Unbundled Product: Hardware/PROM

Unbundled Release: OBP 4.22.11, POST 4.22.11, OBDIAG 4.22.11

Relevant Architectures: sun fire v440, netra 440
```

Update 3. Flash OBP PROM Update 4.30.4.a for SUN FIRE V240
ftp://ftp.sovintel.ru/pub/software/Solaris/patches/142700-02.zip
http://bishun.net/misc/sunv240/142700-02.zip